# How can I configure SpringBoot with Thymeleaf and use sec:authentication tag

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im using spring-boot 1.2.5 + thymeleaf + spring security for my application.

I need to display the username in my website, after doing some research seems that I should use code something like:

```
<div sec:authentication="name">The value of the "name" property of
        the authentication object should appear here.</div>
```

However I don't get Thymeleaf to parse that tag.  Please I need some help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Spring Security 3 integration module in your project. These module are Thymeleaf dialect equivalent to Spring security tag lib. These are thymeleaf extra modules and are not a part of the Thymeleaf core.

In your Template Engine Just add the integration module dialect.

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
 ...
  <property name="additionalDialects">
    <set>
      <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
    </set>
  </property>
  ...
</bean>
```

After adding the modules, you can use your following code:

```
<div sec:authentication="name">The value of the "name" property of
    the authentication object should appear here.</div>
```

Thymeleaf equivalent modules can be found [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity). 
Also, refer this [Step by Step tutorial of TheymeLeaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html)

UPDATE:

If you are using Spring Boot, You just need add the dependency in the pom.xml or add the jars in your project.

Comment: You can do better than only provide a link, elaborate a bit more (add a sample next to the link for instance).

Comment: I understand but its not a code related issue. Need to add the modules(or jars) in the project, which I already mentioned here. I provided the link to the tutorial just in case.

Comment: Yes I know but state WHICH modules don't just provide a link be a bit more expressive about the answer. Currently I would mark it as a link only answer...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.    I already have in my project spring-boot + thymeleaf + spring security  configured and working, however I'm not sure how to enable the module for spring security, like the tutorial page said


<property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
          <!-- Note the package would change to 'springsecurity3' if you are using that version -->
          <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
        </set>
      </property>

Comment: Edited my answer. If you are still facing the issue. Please provide the template.

Comment: Well actually he is using Spring Boot so the only thing he needs to do is add a dependency for the thyme leaf security jar and that is it. Spring Boot will automatically register the dialect for him.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.   Seems that we got the problem. I need to include the dependency thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 (like @m-deinum said).  I thought when you include spring-security-starter already include that dependency.  So, after all, I solved it by adding the dependency to the pom no other configuration required.

Comment: Great!! . Well, I mentioned that in the answer :  These are thymeleaf extra modules and are not a part of the Thymeleaf core.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Spring Boot and you would like to use `sec:authentication` or `sec:authorize`, don't forget to include the dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to do three things:

Register component:

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver) {
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
return templateEngine;
}
```

add thymeleaf security definition

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

and finally add to Your gradle repo:

```
compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4")
compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also a problem with `xmlns:sec`. I spent many hours trying to make this work. After a I realized that the problem is register new dialect I tried registering them but nothing worked for me.
And finally after i gathered some pieces of code from internet  **`sec:authorize="hasRole('USER')`** started to work.
I have made a simple project with combination of maven dependencies. It's spring boot + thymeleaf + spring security.

I have there spring boot (not spring 3 or 4) + thymeleaf + spring security, all working fine together.
Config is java based, not xml.

Link to project https://github.com/hackofi/springboot-sec

*pom.xml*

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*WebConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "cz.vse")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }


    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return templateResolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

*WebSecurityConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("pass").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("derp").password("pass").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot, besides adding the compile dependency:

```
compile 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:'2.1.3.RELEASE'
```

I had to add a bean for the dialect:

```
@Bean
IDialect springSecurityDialect() {
    new SpringSecurityDialect()
}
```

Only then does Spring Boot's autoconfiguration pick up the dialect by asking the context for all the `IDialect` beans:

```
public ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration(
        Collection<ITemplateResolver> templateResolvers,
        ObjectProvider<Collection<IDialect>> dialectsProvider) {
    this.templateResolvers = templateResolvers;
    this.dialects = dialectsProvider.getIfAvailable();
}
```