# Spring Security 4 w/ Thymeleaf sec:authorize not working

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use Spring Boot, Spring Security 4, Thymeleaf, and the sec:authorize attribute to be able to show a log out button when the user is logged and a sign up and log in when no user is logged in.  Right now both the sign out and log in button are showing as well as the log out button.  This is what I have in my html so far.

This is at the top of my html page.

```
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Quizbanks</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
```

And this is my list where I'm trying to display the log out and log in buttons at different times using the sec: authorize attribute.

```
        <ul sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a th:href="@{/login}">Login </a></li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/register}">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
            <li>
                <a th:href="@{/logout}">Log out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Also here's my pom.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>QuizbanksBootProject</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong and point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.  Also if there's anything else I need to show you guys to see where the problem is just let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try explained examples: [http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Spring-Security-Integration-issue-tp4025441p4025510.html](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Spring-Security-Integration-issue-tp4025441p4025510.html)

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904857/secauthorize-returning-true-for-both-isauthenticated-and-isanonymous-in-thy/40492335#40492335

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out my problem, all I needed to do was add this to my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You do not need to declare the xml namespace: Just register a bean in your configuration

Comment: I am having the similer problem, but not able to resolve by adding thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4

<thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>  <thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4>
<thymeleaf.layout.dialect>2.2.2</thymeleaf.layout.dialect>
<spring.framework.version>5.0.1.RELEASE</spring.framework.version  <spring.security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>